# Problem with ASP.NET MVC routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes

I have a page that I want it to have 2 different routes: "/Admin/Schedules"   AND   "/Schedules"

"/Admin/Schedules"  if for admin users and the page will render some admin features and it needs to log in... on the other hand, "/Schedules" is for non-logged users and it will render non-admin features...

But, the page is the same and I specifically need these two routes...

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Yes, it is named Admin...And I also have a SchedulesController...

Comment: And theses both Controlles are under a path "Admin"

Comment: Do you use your method in the controller to manipulate the view based on the non-user or user rights?

Comment: No... how can I manipulate the View based on the user??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could accomplish this in the controller as ajma said by just having an if condition  and a switch statement in a method that checks if the user exist like so:

```
    if(UserID !=null)
       {

       switch(UserPreference)
       {
           case 1:
                            action = "Schedules"; 

                            top = TypeOfPage.Admin;
                            view = "Schedules";

                            break;
           default:
                            action = "Schedules"; 
                            top = TypeOfPage.Nonuser;
                            view = "Schedules";
                            break;
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your controller instead of the routing. RedirectToAction or RedirectToRoute can help you.